# Problema com Bundle no servidor

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, mvc, iis

Bom dia,
fui implementar o uso de bundle no meu projeto ASP.NET MVC, no ambiente de desenvolvimento funcionou perfeitamente. Porém quando subo no servidor o mesmo não funciona. Fui debugar no navegador e ele da o seguinte retorno:
"Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html"

Alguém poderia me dar alguma dica de como solucionar este problema?

BundleConfig.cs:

```
        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/auth/css").Include(
            "~/Content/assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css",
            "~/Content/assets/css/user.css",
            "~/Content/font/css/font-awesome.min.css"));
```

View onde faço a chamada:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Recuperar Senha</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/auth/css")
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="loginbox" style="margin-top:50px;" class="mainbox col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
            <div class="panel">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <a class="pull-left" href="@Url.Action("Login")"><i class="fa fa-backward"></i> voltar</a>
                    <div class="panel-title text-center">Esqueceu sua Senha - PráticoERP</div>
                    <hr />
                </div>
                <div style="padding-top:30px" class="panel-body">

                    @Html.Partial("_AlertMessage")

                    @using (Html.BeginForm())
                    {
                        <div style="margin-bottom: 25px" class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
                            @Html.TextBox("login", null, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Login" })
                        </div>

                        <div style="margin-bottom: 25px" class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-bookmark"></i></span>
                            @Html.TextBox("email", null, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Email" })
                        </div>

                        <div style="margin-top:10px" class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-sm-12 controls">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-success" disabled>Recuperar senha</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-12 control">
                                <hr />
                                <div>
                                    Não tem conta?
                                    <a href="@Url.Action("Contato", "Auth")">Entre em contato</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Agradeço dês de já.

Comment: Você está usando qual IIS para testar isso?

Comment: Estou utilizando o IIS 8.5

Comment: O normal, certo? Não o Express.

Comment: Sim, estou usando o normal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

É preciso instalar o recurso de *Static Content* do IIS para que arquivos CSS sejam distribuídos com o tipo MIME correto. Esta configuração pode ser feita através do menu **Ativar ou Desativar Recursos do Windows** (*Add or Remove Windows Features*):

[image: Add Or Remove Windows Features]